# Rank with Ties in R

Tags: r, ranking

I have a list of competitors and point values from a tournament. A lot of competitors are tied. I need a way to rank them in R so that, for example, if four competitors tie for fourth place, the output might look like this:

```
Competitor A: 1 
Competitor B: 2
Competitor C: 3
Competitor D: 4
Competitor E: 4
Competitor F: 4
Competitor G: 4
Competitor F: 8
```

So the next rank after the tie, instead of being 5, would be 8 (because four competitors took up the slots from 4-7).

I know this is a little counter intuitive, but if anyone has any ideas it would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

data

```
v1 <- setNames(c(4, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9), paste('Competitor', LETTERS[1:8]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `min_rank` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
min_rank(v1)
#[1] 2 3 1 4 4 4 4 8
```

Or in `base R`, (from @Steven Beaupré's comments)

```
rank(v1, ties.method = "min")
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(4, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9)
```

Comment: Or using base `rank(v1, ties.method = "min")`